# Is it possible that Google App Engine Access external database like Google App Script

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdbc, google-apps-script

I have try google app script which allows developer access an external database

Both GAE & App script are the product from google.

I have been told that GAE can not connect to an external database since long time ago

I have wonder if google have changed their mind after launching the google cloud sql(which I want to complain that why they don't have a free tier)

It will be strange if they are not providing JDBC connection in GAE but providing it in Google App Script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not strange, its by design since appengine only uses http (s) ports.
You are not prohibited to do so, just write an http based service to wrap your sql wherever u want to have it.
Google cloud sql also has an introductory trial which is free. I doubt they will ever provide permanent  free sql.

Comment: The tail has end, and will not be provided to anyone